# How to fill values from a pandas dataframe to another dataframe with different datetimeindex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. One has a 5 minute granularity (df1), the other is indexed by days (df2). For the sake of  this example the days end at 7:10

df1:

```
            Date    Close
2019-06-20 07:00:00 2927.25
2019-06-20 07:05:00 2927.00
2019-06-20 07:10:00 2926.75
2019-06-21 07:00:00 2932.25
2019-06-21 07:05:00 2932.25
2019-06-21 07:10:00 2931.00
2019-06-24 07:00:00 2941.75
2019-06-24 07:05:00 2942.25
2019-06-24 07:10:00 2941.50
2019-06-25 07:00:00 2925.50
2019-06-25 07:05:00 2926.50
2019-06-25 07:10:00 2926.50
```

df2:

```
            range                       
Date                            
2019-06-20  115.0
2019-06-21  86.0    
2019-06-24  52.0
2019-06-25  132.0
```

Now I’d like to take the values from ‘range’ column of df2 and and inject them repetitive in a new column in df1.

It should look like this:

```
            Date    Close       range
2019-06-20 07:00:00 2927.25     115.0
2019-06-20 07:05:00 2927.00     115.0
2019-06-20 07:10:00 2926.75     115.0
2019-06-21 07:00:00 2932.25     86.0    
2019-06-21 07:05:00 2932.25     86.0    
2019-06-21 07:10:00 2931.00     86.0    
2019-06-24 07:00:00 2941.75     52.0
2019-06-24 07:05:00 2942.25     52.0
2019-06-24 07:10:00 2941.50     52.0
2019-06-25 07:00:00 2925.50     132.0
2019-06-25 07:05:00 2926.50     132.0
2019-06-25 07:10:00 2926.50     132.0
```

Unfortunately I don’t know how to start that’s why there’s no ‘my attempt’ code
How would you do this?

Comment: As a suggestion, I might say look at the merge function in pandas as it looks like it's what you're after: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert the date like columns to pandas datetime series:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index)
```

Use [`Series.dt.date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) + [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map `range` values from `df2` to `df1`:

```
df1['range'] = df1['Date'].dt.date.map(df2.set_index(df2.index.date)['range'])
```

OR its also possible to use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1.assign(k=df1['Date'].dt.date).merge(df2.assign(k=df2.index.date), on='k').drop('k', 1)
```

Result:

```
                  Date    Close  range
0  2019-06-20 07:00:00  2927.25  115.0
1  2019-06-20 07:05:00  2927.00  115.0
2  2019-06-20 07:10:00  2926.75  115.0
3  2019-06-21 07:00:00  2932.25   86.0
4  2019-06-21 07:05:00  2932.25   86.0
5  2019-06-21 07:10:00  2931.00   86.0
6  2019-06-24 07:00:00  2941.75   52.0
7  2019-06-24 07:05:00  2942.25   52.0
8  2019-06-24 07:10:00  2941.50   52.0
9  2019-06-25 07:00:00  2925.50  132.0
10 2019-06-25 07:05:00  2926.50  132.0
11 2019-06-25 07:10:00  2926.50  132.0
```

Comment: The `series.map` solution writes NaN values in the range column. The `DataFrame.merge` solution doesn't work. Error:` 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'date'`

Comment: @stanvooz You first need to convert date columns to pandas datetime series.

Comment: I did, but then the dataframe looks a bit weird and I get a warning, in addition the range column has NaN values: `/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py:617: UserWarning: merging between different levels can give an unintended result (1 levels on the left, 2 on the right)
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a loop, do something like that:

```
for i in df2["Date"]:
     for j in df1["Date"]:
          if i==j:
              df1['range'] = df2['range']
```

Answer (score 0):

1. need to ensure your Date columns are dates
2. floor them to day granularity so they are same across data frames
3. cleanup the columns

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Date":["2019-06-19T23:00:00.000Z","2019-06-19T23:05:00.000Z","2019-06-19T23:10:00.000Z","2019-06-20T23:00:00.000Z","2019-06-20T23:05:00.000Z","2019-06-20T23:10:00.000Z","2019-06-23T23:00:00.000Z","2019-06-23T23:05:00.000Z","2019-06-23T23:10:00.000Z","2019-06-24T23:00:00.000Z","2019-06-24T23:05:00.000Z","2019-06-24T23:10:00.000Z"],"Close":[2927.25,2927,2926.75,2932.25,2932.25,2931,2941.75,2942.25,2941.5,2925.5,2926.5,2926.5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Date":["2019-06-19T16:00:00.000Z","2019-06-20T16:00:00.000Z","2019-06-23T16:00:00.000Z","2019-06-24T16:00:00.000Z"],"range":[115,86,52,132]})

df1.Date = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date)
df2.Date = pd.to_datetime(df2.Date)


df1.assign(day=df1.Date.dt.floor("D"))\
    .merge(df2.assign(day=df2.Date.dt.floor("D")), on="day")\
    .drop(["day","Date_y"],1).rename({"Date_x":"Date"},axis=1)
```

**output**

```
                     Date    Close  range
2019-06-19 23:00:00+00:00  2927.25    115
2019-06-19 23:05:00+00:00  2927.00    115
2019-06-19 23:10:00+00:00  2926.75    115
2019-06-20 23:00:00+00:00  2932.25     86
2019-06-20 23:05:00+00:00  2932.25     86
2019-06-20 23:10:00+00:00  2931.00     86
2019-06-23 23:00:00+00:00  2941.75     52
2019-06-23 23:05:00+00:00  2942.25     52
2019-06-23 23:10:00+00:00  2941.50     52
2019-06-24 23:00:00+00:00  2925.50    132
2019-06-24 23:05:00+00:00  2926.50    132
2019-06-24 23:10:00+00:00  2926.50    132
```